# Where can I get mxClient.js unminified source code?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

In drawio [source code](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), it looks like mxClient is only provided in minified format.

Where can I get drawio's mxClient.js unminifiend source code?

I tried to look up mxClient unminified version online but I only found [V4.2.2](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph) which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mxClient.js` file relates to mxGraph with is End Of Life as of 2020-11-09. See the [README of mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/#readme) repository.

The developers of draw.io continue to maintain their own private version of mxGraph and include it in draw.io. As it is a private version, they don't want the source code to be publicly available, so they don't (and probably won't) provide an unminified `mxClient.js` file.

What do you expect to find in this new mxGraph version?